# UILocalNotification multiple firing

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, uilocalnotification

I schedule a `UILocalNotification` at at specific date, and the notification is fired correctly, But the problem is that I receive multiple alerts at random dates for same notification even though the notification is not repeated (repeatInterval = 0 ).

Another note, when I receive the notification at first time , it appears correctly in notification center, but later when I receive the multiple alerts nothing updated in notification center.

Please note that this event is repeated daily, but the notification not get repeated.

Any solution for this issue?

Comment: Most likely these are old, unexpired notifications you did not cancel, left over from earlier test runs.

Comment: I cancel all notification and then start scheduling the future ones, but this case only happens when the event is an repeated, and start at 12:00 am

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect you are never calling:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications]
```

These notifications appear to be "old" notifications that haven't been cancelled and are still due to fire. Did you ever have a repeat interval? Some of these notifications could be repeated from very old notifications

Comment: I cancel all notification and then start scheduling the future ones, but this case only happens when the event is an repeated, and start at 12:00 am

Comment: This helped, Thank you